# Open External Link with Phonegap Cordova in iOS without Childbrowser Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, childbrowser

Can I open external links with Phonegap Cordova (1.8.1) in iOS without the Childbrowser plugin?

Most of the tutorials that talk about this topic are outdated.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using

```
<a href="my-external-url" target="_blank">a link like this</a>
```

Or

```
window.location.href="my-external-url"
```

Will open the external URL in the Phonegap webview, not in a browser. If you have this working as you claim, you have solved a really big issue for all phonegap users. Some literature on this topic.

- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/make_links_use_external_broswer_consistently
- https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags
- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open with "_system" as the window name ([InAppBrowser](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser))

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap does this support?

Comment: It exists in Apache Cordova since 2.3.0